# How to export selected data from my ASPx DevExpress gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, devexpress

I need to export to XLS the selected row of my DevExpress GridView.
When i try to export my grid, it creates an empty file. I think it is due to the callback that clear the data in my grid before exporting.

This is samples of my ASPx page.

The Load data button

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/Images/load.png" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

The gridview

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" KeyFieldName="car">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Category" VisibleIndex="1" FieldName="category"
                Name="category" GroupIndex="0" SortIndex="0" SortOrder="Ascending">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Car" VisibleIndex="2" FieldName="car" Name="car">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        </Columns>
        <SettingsPager PageSize="100">
        </SettingsPager>
        <Settings ShowFooter="True" />

        <GroupSummary>
            <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="car" SummaryType="Count" />
        </GroupSummary>

    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

The GridExporter

```
    <dx:ASPxGridViewExporter ID="gridExport" runat="server" GridViewID="grid" ExportedRowType="Selected" />
```

The create file button

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="createFile" runat="server" Text="Create File"      UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="createFile_Click">
                    <Image Url="~/Styles/Images/save.png">
                    </Image>
    </dx:ASPxButton>
```

Now the code behind.

When I click the load button, i create fake datas for my tests.

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateFakeData();
    }
```

I create my datas in a DataTable Object. And then i bind my dataTable with my grid.

```
grid.DataSource = fakes;
grid.DataBind();
```

Everything seem to works great but when i click the export button, nothing is exported.

```
    protected void createFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridExport.WriteXlsToResponse();
    }
```

I followed the [DevExpress tutoria to export selected rows in ASPl](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxgridviewdemos/exporting/ExportSelected.aspx). But it seems that my page is refreshed so i loose the data binded with the grid before the export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the postback, as I expected, I needed a way to keep my gridView Datas somewhere and reload it after the postback.

I added the *OnDataBinding* attribute to my gridView

```
 <dx:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" Caption="My car collection"
OnDataBinding="grid_DataBinding" KeyFieldName="car_model">
```

In the code behind, I coded the *grid-DataBinding* function so it restores the data using the data stocked in the session previously.

```
  protected void grid_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["gridData"] != null)
            {
                // Assign the data source in grid_DataBinding
                grid.DataSource = Session["gridData"];
            }
        }
```

Don't forget to save the data in the session when desired. (I did it right after the search)

```
 protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {

            datas = FindCars(input.Text);

            grid.DataSource = datas;
            grid.DataBind();

            //Store data in the session
            Session["gridData"] = this.datas;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation when I was binding data to an ASPXGridView in the code behind.  I was able to solve it by rebinding in the button click, before the export line.

```
protected void createFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grid.DataSource = fakes;        
    grid.DataBind();        
    gridExport.WriteXlsToResponse();
}
```

Comment: It shows that the WriteXlsToResponse() does a callback because your code allow me to export the data but not onely the selected rows.

Comment: Yes, in my case I just needed the grid exported as is, the filtering was done with the data in the code behind.  If you are able to put the DataSource in the properties of the control (instead of the code), it should do what you want.